# Find closest column to pandas dataframe avg

Tags: python, pandas

I have a certain pandas dataframe, for example

```
  A.1 A.2 A.3 A.4 B.1 B.2 B.3
0 1   5   8   10  ... 
1 2   4   6   7   ... 
2 3   3   6   1   ...
```

I want to calculate avg column of pandas dataframe by rows, only for columns containing 'A' , e.g :

```
A.avg
6
4.75
3.25
```

and then find which of the columns of 'A's is a nearest (least rms error) to the avg and get it column name (here it would be A.2)

The first part is pretty straightforward but I mosty struggle with the second part

Edit: This is what I do to find a max column id (I have a list of substrings(such as A,B,C and etc.) and I perform a sweep on  a dataframe):

```
max_id_per_substring = [
            self.table[[column for column in list(self.table) if substring in column]].idxmax(axis=1).iloc[-1]  for substring in self.all_substrings]
```

Comment: Can you include the code for the first part, that is 'pretty straightforward'?

Comment: i put some example where I do the same thing to find a max column id (I have a list of substrings and I perform a sweep on  a dataframe):

`max_id_per_substring = [
            self.table[[column for column in list(self.table) if substring in column]].idxmax(axis=1).iloc[-1]  for substring in self.all_substrings]`

Comment: Question edited to clarify it more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most convenient to carry out the calculation in numpy where you can use broadcasting. So we first take all columns like `A.` and convert them to a numpy array. To make use of broadcasting to do the subtraction of the mean on the transposed data, square the results and find the column number with the minimum sum.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A.1':[1,2,3], 'A.2':[5,4,3], 'A.3':[8,6,6], 'A.4':[10,7,1], 'B.1':[0,0,0]})

arr = df.filter(like='A.').to_numpy().T
col_number = ((arr - arr.mean(0))**2).sum(1).argmin()

print(df.filter(like='A.').columns[col_number])
#A.2
```